# WinJS: How to resolve a global resource directly within an option

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, winjs

Is there a way to evaluate a global resource using WinJS directly in my WinJS control options definition, not using `data-win-res` attribute, because the specific option is a complex object?

Here is what I have:

```
<div id="CustomControl" data-win-control="My.Custom.NameSpace.Control" data-win-options="{
     opt1: 123,
     opt2: [
         { prop1: WinJS.Resources.getString('Global_Resource_String').value },
         ...
     }">
</div>
```

The following attempt to evaluate the resource crashes with an error that the interpreter expects a bracket but instead saw a left parentheses. You can see why I cannot easily generate a setter for this option and `data-win-res="{ winControl: {opt2[0].prop1: "Global_Resource_String"} }"` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that inside the `data-win-options` attribute no function evaluation can be performed and thus the issue with evaluating global resources. If I want to assign a complex option to a global resource I need to do the function evaluation in a global variable and then assign to it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var resource = WinJS.Resources.getString('Global_Resource_String').value;
</script>

<div id="CustomControl" data-win-control="My.Custom.NameSpace.Control" data-win-options="{
     opt1: 123,
     opt2: [
         { prop1: resource },
         ...
     }">
</div>
```